# segmentation fault in a scanf c++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, scanf

In my program, at some point, I make a `scanf(" %d %d", &num1, &num2);` and I keep getting a SegmentationFault. I don't understand why.. I mean, they're `int`. I'm not sure if I should be allocating memory for them.
This is the full code.

```
typedef struct my_type{
   int attr1;
   bool attr2;
} my_type;

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {

    int testCase, result, totalDom, numLines, num1, num2; 
    int aux_map_int = 0, linesScanned = 0;
    bool firstTime;
    scanf("%d\n %d %d", &testCase, &totalDom, &numLines);
    printf("totalDom: %d; numLines: %d\n", totalDom, numLines);

    std::map<int, std::vector<my_type> > my_map;

    while(aux_map_int < testCase+1){
        std::vector<my_type> my_vector;
        firstTime=true;

        while (linesScanned < numLines) {

            std::cin>>num_dom>>num_next_dom; /** SEGFAULT **/


            if(firstTime){
                my_vector[0].attr1 = num1;
                my_vector[0].attr2 = true;
                firstTime=false;
            }

            my_vector[num1].attr1 = num2;
            my_vector[num1].attr2 = false;

            linesScanned++;
        }
        aux_map_int++;
        my_map.insert(std::pair<int, std::vector<my_type> >(aux_map_int, my_vector));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a small complete program that demonstrates the heart of your question?

Comment: Hard to tell what is going on without more code, sample input, etc.

Comment: show some more code... It's hard to help without seeing the code

Comment: You probably don't want those spaces in the format string.

Comment: If they are doubles, then I wonder if the problem is `%d` instead of `%lf`. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string#Format_string_specifications)

Comment: The actual code you have posted here doesn't look like it's a problem. It could be if you are doing something wrong in declaring num1 and num2, but unlikely.

Comment: Use `cin` which helps to avoid format-specifiers.

Comment: [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) documentation, see particularly the `format` section.

Comment: In general, please use `std::cin` instead (or at least use `sscanf`). `scanf` is *notoriously* hard to use properly. http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Comment: I tried that too. And I still get segfault

Comment: I think you're missing the code that declares my_type

Comment: @carleeto just added it

Comment: @FredericoNobredeCarvalho You're also missing the declarations for num_dom. Your code also does not compile because my_vector is also not in scope on the last line. That last line only makes sense if its inside the while loop.

Comment: @FredOverflow: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string says that `%Lf` (note the capital "L") is `long double` but `%lf` is `double`.

Comment: @carleeto thank you for pointing those two errors. mostly because It wasn't supposed to be num_dom and yes num1. Made those changes, and I still get the same error. I debugged it the very wrong way (with `std::cout`) and the program doesn't go past the `std::cin`

Answer (score 5):

%d expects pointer to int. According to your own words you are passing pointers to doubles.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: Your segmentation fault is not because of scanf, but because you're inserting elements in a vector inside an infinite while loop. Check whether aux_map_int is getting incremented :)

```
 std::cin>>num_dom>>num_next_dom; /** SEGFAULT **/
```

I'm going to assume that line should read

```
 std::cin>>num1>>num2; /** SEGFAULT **/
```

If it does, you get a segfault when you try to insert into my_vector in your inner while loop:

```
        if(firstTime){
            my_vector[0].attr1 = num1;
            my_vector[0].attr2 = true;
            firstTime=false;
        }

        my_vector[num1].attr1 = num2;
        my_vector[num1].attr2 = false;
```

Before that point, you have not inserted anything into the vector and you're trying to read from it. Here is code that will segfault too

```
#include <vector>

typedef struct my_type{
   int attr1;
   bool attr2;
} my_type;

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) 
{
    std::vector<my_type> v;
    v[0].attr1 = 1;
    v[0].attr1 = true;
}
```

Fix the code above and you will have learnt how to fix your issue. Sorry I can't give you the answer :)

Also, is there a specific reason you're using scanf over std::cin? If the answer is no, then use this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
....
std::cin>>num1>>num2;
```

It would work just as well, without any of the usual scanf hassles.

If you must use scanf, I would refer you to its documentation. Your problem is that you're not using the correct format specifier. Rather than just tell you what it is, I'd rather [you read it for yourself](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf).

It seems from the code you've posted that the reason you're using scanf is to deal with white space. If this is the case, use std::cin and your whitespace issues are history.

Comment: @FredericoNobredeCarvalho Updated the answer. The segmentation fault has nothing to do with scanf :)

Comment: thank you for pointing that other error, but I still get segmentation fault and can't figure out why

Comment: @FriedRike I've updated my answer. While I know what the problem is, StackOverflow is about learning. So while I have not told you what you need to do to fix it, I hope I've pointed you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

as @Tomek says. %d for int. %f for float 
Try this:

```
double num1, num2;
char str[128];
scanf("%f %f", &num1, &num2);
```

Comment: what would the `str` be for?